# rbind an empty xts with an xts

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have an xts object (single row) called `Portfolio` that looks like this:

```
               A      B      C       D       E
2010-01-04 61006.1 61628.5 62072.1 60068.66 60088.47
```

`"Portfolio"` changes for every iteration of a for loop and I'd like to create an xts table called `Portfolio.Table` that keeps a history of `"Portfolio"`.

I'm doing `Portfolio.Table <- xts()` and the end of each iteration in the for loop I'm doing:  `Portfolio.Table <- rbind(Portfolio.Table,Portfolio)` but I get an error:`data must have same number of columns to bind by row`

How do I create a blank xts object with set number of column? Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Can't you create an empty list first an fill in `"Portfolio"` in each iteration? At the end you might do `do.call(rbind, Portfolio.Table)`. BTW Can you make a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `rbind.fill`:

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(data,data2)
```

Comment: rbind.fill does not work with xts objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `p` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, start out with `NULL`, instead of `xts()`, as shown below.  After the code below is run `p.table` equals `p`.

```
p.table <- NULL
p.table <- rbind(p.table, p)
```

### Note

We assume that we have an xts object

```
library(xts)

v <- c(A = 61006.1, B = 61628.5, C = 62072.1, D = 60068.66, E = 60088.47)
p <- xts(t(v), as.Date("2010-01-04"))
```